# Youtube Playlist iframe - Display videos by default

Tags: html, css, iframe, youtube, youtube-iframe-api

I have an embedded YouTube playlist on my website.

```
<iframe width="1000px" height="600px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list={{list_id}}"
                            frameborder="0" rel="0" showinfo="1" modestbranding="1"
                            allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

How can I show the list of the videos when the page loads?

For example,

**How it looks now (when the page loads)**

[image]

**How I want it to look (when the page loads)**

[image]